# socket.cork is not a function when trying to initiate request through socks proxy (TOR)

Tags: node.js, socket.io, agent, socks

```
_http_outgoing.js:797
  socket.cork();
         ^

TypeError: socket.cork is not a function
    at ClientRequest._flushOutput (_http_outgoing.js:797:10)
    at ClientRequest._flush (_http_outgoing.js:776:16)
....
```

Getting above error when trying to http.get() or request() using SOCKS proxy agent previously created with "proxysocket" library.

I am trying to create working agent to use it socket.io, or ws or http to make connections via SOCKS proxy. I tries "proxysocket" library and its agent gives me error above.

```
let agent = proxysocket.createAgent("127.0.0.1", 9050);
request("http://www.google.com", {agent: agent}, (err, res, body) => {
    if (err){
        console.log("Http request error: " + err);
    } else{
        console.log("Http request connection success!");
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
        console.log(body)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution. I tried tons of proxy agents, and the only working one is "socks5-http-client".

Other agents were giving all kinds of errors when using SOCKS5 protocol.

```
const http = require("http");
const Agent = require("socks5-http-client/lib/Agent"); // Constructor 
let agent = new Agent({
        socksHost: 'localhost', // Defaults to 'localhost'.
        socksPort: 9050 // Defaults to 1080.
    });
    http.get({
              hostname: "www.google.com", // Can be also onion address if used behind TOR
              port: 80,
              agent: agent,
              method: 'GET'
          }, (res)=>{
               console.log("Connected");
               res.pipe(process.stdout);
               //Process res
           }).on('error', (err) => {
               console.error(`Got error: ${err.message}`);
           });
```

Such agent can be passed into any kinds of libraries that use http.Agent such as socket.io, ws, etc.